# SqlDbType does not contain definition for XML issue in .net framework 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I use below code in my project it gives me error mentioned above.
I am using .net framework 1.1. It is working in .net framework 1.1? I searched on google and it's says it supports 1.1 but not working in my project.

```
oCommandp.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Bcmst_XML", SqlDbType.Xml) 
    { Value = new SqlXml(new XmlTextReader(XMLBoClientMaster.InnerXml, 
      XmlNodeType.Document, null)) 
    });
```

Comment: "I am using .net framework 1.1" - I think I've found the problem. Serious question: *why* are you using .NET Framework 1.1? Are you sure you weren't looking for .NET Core 1.1? (and even that is obsolete; .NET Core 3.0 should be the "go-to" today) (for reference: mainstream support for 1.1 ended in 2008; *extended* support ended in 2013; it is *actively dangerous* to be using this now)

Comment: Looking at the documentation from the .NET Framework Version 1.1 for the SqlDbType enum it seems like back then it did not contain any definition for Xml (and quite a few other values too, like Time, DateTime2, DateTimeOffset and others). Link to .NET 1.1 documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=netframework-1.1

Comment: "I searched on google and it's says it supports 1.1" - I *suspect* you're looking at the "Applies to" at the bottom of the learn.microsoft.com page; that is referring to the *enum*, not any specific element; some elements were added later; `SqlDbType.Xml` looks to have been added in .NET Framework 2.0